# Key is still referenced from table "old_table"

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, model, migration

I am developing and rest api with Django rest_framework. For notifications, I used **fcm_django** package. But after a while, I removed that package and used another package for notifications. Then, when I try to delete a user that created when I have fcm_django models. I got this error in terminal. New users does not give that error. I cannot remove old users. But there is nothing to do with fcm_django of any models now. I am already created new migrations after remove that fcm model. What can I do? Thanks.

Error:

```
update or delete on table "user_user" violates foreign key constraint "fcm_django_fcmdevice_user_id_6cdfc0a2_fk_user_user_id" on table "fcm_django_fcmdevice"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(25) is still referenced from table "fcm_django_fcmdevice".
```

Comment: Can you manually delete all records in the remaining `fcm_django` tables that are still in your database?

Comment: You need to remove all references to id=25 in fcm_django_fcmdevice

Comment: Thanks for the advise guys. It is solved. I truncated the table that I don't use anymore.